# Issue with put closest() and html() together in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have created a voting system for my project. I have tried using the below code which is working properly but `html()` is not working with this. Can anybody help me with this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".up").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active_vote');
    $('.active_vote').closest('.rating').html('18');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="suggestions">
  <li id="59">
    <div class="vote active ">
      <div class="support-feature-request-voted">
        <div class="rating">
          10
        </div>
        <span>Voted</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">hii</div>
    <div class="desc">desc1</div><br>
    <a class="up">UP VOTE</a><a class="down">DOWN VOTE</a>
  </li>
  <li id="60">
    <div class="vote active ">
      <div class="support-feature-request-voted">
        <div class="rating">
          8
        </div>
        <span>Voted</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">hello</div>
    <div class="desc">desc2</div><br>
    <a class="up">UP VOTE</a><a class="down">DOWN VOTE</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `.rating` isn't a parent of the `.up` element which triggers the `click` event.

To fix this you could use `closest()` to get the nearest common parent, the `li` in this case, then `find()` to get the `.rating`. Also note that both statements in the event handler can be combined. Try this:

```js
let result2 = "Lorem ipsum";

jQuery(function() {
  $(".up").on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active_vote').closest('li').find('.rating').html(result2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="suggestions">
  <li id="59">
    <div class="vote active">
      <div class="support-feature-request-voted">
        <div class="rating">
          10
        </div>
        <span>Voted</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">hii</div>
    <div class="desc">desc1</div><br>
    <a class="up">UP VOTE</a><a class="down">DOWN VOTE</a>
  </li>
  <li id="60">
    <div class="vote active">
      <div class="support-feature-request-voted">
        <div class="rating">
          8
        </div>
        <span>Voted</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">hello</div>
    <div class="desc">desc2</div><br>
    <a class="up">UP VOTE</a><a class="down">DOWN VOTE</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parent` with `find`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".up").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active_vote');
    $(this).parent().find('.rating').html('result2'); // Your upvote logic goes with result2
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="suggestions">
  <li id="59">
    <div class="vote active ">
      <div class="support-feature-request-voted">
        <div class="rating">
          10
        </div>
        <span>Voted</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">hii</div>
    <div class="desc">desc1</div><br>
    <a class="up">UP VOTE</a><a class="down">DOWN VOTE</a>
  </li>
  <li id="60">
    <div class="vote active ">
      <div class="support-feature-request-voted">
        <div class="rating">
          8
        </div>
        <span>Voted</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">hello</div>
    <div class="desc">desc2</div><br>
    <a class="up">UP VOTE</a><a class="down">DOWN VOTE</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```